# android Expandable listview default indicator image

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I am going to hide indicator of groups using this code in my adapter

```
if ( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
            holder. Indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
        } else {
            holder. Indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            holder. Indicator.setImageResource( isExpanded ? R.drawable.list_group_expanded : R.drawable.list_group_closed );
        }
```

But I want to use defult expandable list item images instead of `list_group_expanded` and `list_group_closed` how can I find default icon of indicator?Can some one help me ?thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
holder. Indicator.setImageResource( isExpanded ? android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float : android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float );
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the original image that shows in Expandable list view

Comment: @MajidHojati: hi, sorry for replying so late ... where have you reached with this ?

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answer,I have set another image that I have extracted from an app